# TypeError: 'LogisticRegression' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, logistic-regression

```
logistic_regression.fit= LogisticRegression()
logreg.predict.fit([X_train,y_train])
y_pred=logistic_regression.predict(X_test)
```

TypeError: 'LogisticRegression' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

You can import Logistic Regression first:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
```

Then you can create and fit it:

```
log_regressor = LogisticRegression(solver = 'lbfgs') 
log_regressor.fit([X_train, Y_train])  # perform regression
Y_pred = log_regressor.predict(X_test)  # make predictions
```

You can use another solvers or a default solver.

Answer (score 0):

I assume You want to train model and do some test on your model. Try this:

```py
logistic_regression = LogisticRegression()
logistic_regression.fit([X_train,y_train])
y_pred = logistic_regression.predict(X_test)
```

I think in Your code the major problem is variables name convention:

- `logistic_regression.fit` - dot in variable name
- `logreg.predict.fit` - what is logreg? what is predict here?